# Get a subset of a generator

Tags: python, generator

I have a generator function and want to get the first ten items from it; my first attempt was:

```
my_generator()[:10]
```

This doesn't work because generators aren't subscriptable, as the error tells me. Right now I have worked around that with:

```
list(my_generator())[:10]
```

This works since it converts the generator to a list; however, it's inefficient and defeats the point of having a generator. Is there some built-in, Pythonic equivalent of `[:10]` for generators?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
import itertools

itertools.islice(mygenerator(), 10)
```

`itertools` has a number of utilities for working with iterators.  `islice` takes start, stop, and step arguments to slice an iterator just as you would slice a list.

Comment: actually use:  itertools.islice( mygenerator(), 10 )

Comment: @SilentGhost well, when I tried it I got this error:
   import itertools

   def sumUp():
    x = 20; z = 0
    for y in range(x+1):
        z +=1
        yield z

   for z in itertools.islice(sumUp, 5):
       print z

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Data\code\Febrl\src\z.py", line 9, in <module>
    for z in itertools.islice(sumUp, 5):
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
python 2.6

Comment: Verified that need function call () to actually make the generator. But if you do mygenerator=sumUp() before for then SilentGhost and Ned are right. sumUp is not generator, it's result is.

Comment: in fact, to get the first few generated elements as a list, one can do `list(itertools.islice(mygenerator(), 10))` .

Comment: Why isn't `my_generator()[:10]` equivalent to `islice(mygenerator(), 10)` for all iterables though?

Comment: @endolith `my_generator()[:10]` is an error. You can't subscript a generator. You could do something like `list(my_generator())[:10]`, because `list` is subscriptable, but that is inefficient because it requires exhausting the generator (impossible if the generator is infinite), then throwing away all but the first 10 items.  `islice(mygenerator(), 10)` will get just the first 10 items from the generator. This works even for infinite generators.

Comment: I fixed the example to call the generator function to get the generator.

Answer (score 7):

to clarify the above comments:

```
from itertools import islice

def fib_gen():
    a, b = 1, 1
    while True:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

assert [1, 1, 2, 3, 5] == list(islice(fib_gen(), 5))
```